# Auth0 Angular 2 sso single sign on

Tags: angular, auth0

I have just started playing around with auth0 and I am trying to create a proof of concept.

I am trying to create a single sign on solution in angular 2. Can anyone point me to any example code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDHihQ5hB5I). This gives a basic application with Auth0 service.

Answer (score 0):

I know It is an old question, But if anyone is looking for the solution then
[Github Repo example of sso in angular 2](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular-2-authentication-tutorial)

And a Detail explanation of this example.

https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/

I hope It will help somebody.