# SSO Integration with Angular6 application

Tags: javascript, angular, single-sign-on, angular6

I am new to the Angular application. I would need to a suggestion to implement  SSO Integration with Angular6 (SPA). I didn't get anything on the net for the complete tutorial.

Basically, I am a php developer and I did SSO integration with php applications. Since Angular6 is UI, I don't know how to manage the secret and redirection and other things with Angular6.

So It would be better if someone suggests me steps (or Github samples) to implement Angular6 & SSO Integration and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: you can use libraries like auth0 that will do this for you, if it interests you I will write out proper implementation

Comment: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590302/auth0-angular-2-sso-single-sign-on), [auth0 tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/), [the github page for tutorial](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular-2-authentication-tutorial)

Comment: [this](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) library handles all for you in angular app, if you want to see an example check [this](https://github.com/DooMachine/MicroStarter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been working for Comcast and they have their own SSO with (Client id and Call back URL). So i don't know what to go with Auth0. Do you guys know any library in node package for Angular that handles for SSO?. Because i have checked Auth0, they have their own package like '"auth0-js": "^9.4.1" for Angular,' And i think, it work only with Auth0 client id and all. But in my case, it will be different.

Comment: I think this might help you https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/

Comment: Hello, I used keycloak, this have a javascript adapter. Here an example: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-angular2.

Comment: you can use iodc library => https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client to make a SSO authentication :)

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011649/1235935

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to integrate with multiple sso in my applications.
Currently, i already integrated sso ( jwt, kerberos, saml2, ...)

We have an angular app and rest api ...

```
/front-end/sso/method 
( method can be saml, jwt, kerberos )
```

When user visit any font-end sso url, it will be redirected to rest-api to handle sign on:

```
/back-end/sso/method?callback=frontend-url
```

So all sso requests are also handled at server...

You can control/manage it easily with (php or java ...)

If success, we will redirect user to front-end url with a token. Token can be put in header to hide from eye of user.

```
/front-end/sso/method?token=abc
```

If fail, we will redirect user with error message

```
/front-end/sso/method?error=Invalid....
```

PS: i choose this implementation because i am in favor of back end language and don't want to show many information at front-end ( like saml configuration ... )