# Laravel 5.6 - Passport JWT httponly cookie SPA authentication for self consuming API?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf-protection, laravel-passport, cookie-httponly

**NOTE: I had 4 bounties on this question, but non of the upvoted answers below are the answer needed for this question. Everything needed is in Update 3 below, just looking for Laravel code to implement.**

---

**UPDATE 3: This flow chart is *exactly* the flow I am trying to accomplish, everything below is the original question with some older updates. This flow chart sums up everything needed.**

The green parts in the flow chart below are the parts that I know how to do. The red parts along with their side notes is what I am looking for help accomplishing using Laravel code.

[image]

---

I have done a lot of research but the information always ended up short and not complete when it comes to using Laravel with a JWT httponly cookie for a self consuming API (most tutorials online only show JWT being stored in local storage which is not very secure). It looks like httponly cookie containing a JWT by Passport should be used to identify the user on the Javascript side when sent with every request to the server to validate that the user is who they say they are.

There are also some additional things that are needed to have a complete picture of how to make this setup work which I haven't come across in a single tutorial which covers this:

1. Laravel Passport (not tymon auth) to generate encrypted JWT and send it as httponly cookie as response after login from JS side. What middleware to use? If refresh tokens add more security, how to implement?
2. JavaScript (axios for example) api pseudo code that makes call to auth endpoint, how is httponly cookie passed to backend, and how does backend verify token is valid.
3. If single account is logged in from multiple devices, then a device is stolen, how to revoke access from all the authed user devices (assuming user does Change Password from a logged in device they have control over)?
4. What would Login/Register, Logout, Change Password, Forgot Password controller methods typically look like to handle the creation/validating/revoking of tokens?
5. CSRF token integration.

I hope an answer to this question serves as an easy to follow guide for future readers and those struggling at the moment to find an answer covering the above points on a self consuming API.

**UPDATE 1:**

1. Please note I tried the `CreateFreshApiToken` before, but that didn't work when it comes to revoking tokens of the user (for points 3 and 4 above). This is based on [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/507#issuecomment-430997606) by a core laravel developer, when talking about the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware:

> JWT tokens created by this middleware aren't stored anywhere. They
>   can't be revoked or "not exist". They simply provide a way for your
>   api calls to be authed through the laravel_token cookie. It isn't
>   related to access tokens.
>       Also: you normally wouldn't use tokens issued by clients on the same app which issues them. You'd use them in a first or third party
>   app. Either use the middleware or the client issued tokens but not
>   both at the same time.

So it seems to be able to cater to points 3 and 4 to revoke tokens, it's not possible to do so if using the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware.

2. On the client side, it seems `Authorization: Bearer <token>` is not the way to go when dealing with the secure httpOnly cookie. I think the request/response are supposed to include the secure httpOnly cookie as a request/response header, like this based on the laravel docs:

> When using this method of authentication, the default Laravel
>   JavaScript scaffolding instructs Axios to always send the X-CSRF-TOKEN
>   and X-Requested-With headers.

```
headerswindow.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': (csrf_token goes here)
};
```

This is also the reason I am looking for a solution which covers all the points above. Apologies, I am using Laravel 5.6 not 5.5.

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems the **Password Grant/Refresh Token Grant** combo is the way to go. Looking for an easy to follow implementation guide using **Password Grant/Refresh Token Grant** combo.

> **Password Grant:**
>   This grant is suitable when dealing with the client that we trust,
>   like a mobile app for our own website. In this case, the client sends
>   the user's login credentials to the authorization server and the
>   server directly issues the access token.
>
> **Refresh Token Grant:**
>   When the server issues an access token, it also sets an expiry for the
>   access token. Refresh token grant is used when we want to refresh the
>   access token once it is expired. In this case, authorization server
>   will send a refresh token while issuing the access token, which can be
>   used to request a new access token.

I am looking for an easy to implement, straight forward, holistic answer using the **Password Grant/Refresh Token Grant** combo that covers all the parts of the above original 5 points with httpOnly secure cookie, creating/revoking/refreshing tokens, login cookie creation, logout cookie revoking, controller methods, CSRF, etc.

Comment: I used Passport and Oauth2 of Luca Desgasperi for Laravel. When it come to Mobile app and Javascript it's not secure with Password Grant Type. Only Authorization Code flow is ok. But Tokens must not persist more than 2 minutes to 60 minutes or more depending of the sensitivity of the data. Facebook tokens is 2 minutes + 1 time usage now. With Authorization Code grant type, the browser ask for Username and Password and ask for permission to access your App, or your Own Website (that you can allow by default), and then send only a token with expiration time, that refreshes each period of time

Comment: @KeitelDOG Thank you for your input, but that package only goes up to Laravel 5.3, also they depracated it in favor for Passport. As stated, I am looking for a holistic approach/solution/implementation guide which covers all the points above.

Comment: I know, that's what I've switched to Passport. Passport is better, and the last version can even control revoking a user token in a particular client as your want in your point 3.

Comment: Hello, in our SPA Laravel application, we login the user using default web authentication (session guard). We also generate a csrf_token and place it inside a meta before loading the SPA application. After doing both, we use CreateFreshApiToken middleware to determine if the SPA needs a now token or not. Finally consume the token to authenticate/authorize from api. Is this what you want?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN I added an update regarding why `CreateFreshApiToken` didn't work for me. Cannot revoke those tokens... Looking for a solution which covers all the above points and works well and coherently together.

Comment: @Wonka dear if you find any solution for your question please add your answer here so other can implement like your requirement ..

Comment: @Wonka i still dont understand why you want to use a stateless solution (JWT authentification) in a statefull protocol (cookies and such)

Comment: @N69S I was using JWT and storing it in local storage. When I learned about storing the token in local storage being a storage vulnerability, the more secure approach appeared to be to store the token in http only secure cookie. It does not have to be JWT, but just a way to identify the user via the cookie, but also needed the ability to revoke a token, incase it was stolen from the user somehow, the server needs to know which token(s) to revoke based on the specific user.

Comment: The reason why you should save the refresh token as a HttpOnly cookie is to prevent Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: @Wonka so we are talking more about the session cookies than the JWT system itself. anyhow, since with the token (anyone) you can identifie the user, you just need to mark the user (via an attribute for example) when he's been able to authenticate. let's say you want to reset all the user's sessions; just set that attribute to `now` and any token issued before that time is invalid. you might need to declare your own `middleware` for that.

Comment: @N69S here cookies are not stateful. Here cookies are used just to store a value is the client system and the value is sent with every request. No state is maintained in the server for the cookie (unlike session cookies). Token invalidation or revoking is usually done by the auth server, in which case it keeps a track of all tokens in some kind of database and mark the tokens for invalidation. When the client / resource server goes to the auth server for token refresh (due to expiry of access token), auth server gives negative response. In pwd cred grant type auth server and res serv are same

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman I need a solution/answer, not reputation. I already had 4 bounties on this question, and all over the internet people are looking for a solution. This is just on SO with at least 40 people so far showing interest and 10 favorited the question.

Comment: I have implemented a solution that you asking for, but you have missed a few important points. However, I have flagged this question because this question have so many sub-questions. There exist many detailed instructions how to implement this, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/ or https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

Comment: @GillsoftAB Thank you, I looked them over and confirmed what I already knew. Just looking for a Laravel specific code implementation that covers the password grant + CSRF integration for SPA.

Comment: Just a note on this approach. Headers can be easily spoofed, and it is actually possible to "borrow" cookies from another domain. This is true even if Content Security Policy(CSP), XSS and many other security techniques are used. You are assuming that the browser WILL follow the specifications, but I can inform you that is just plain wrong. No one is just going to hand over a solution to you, here at StckOverflow you get some parts and someone points you in the right direction. That's why I gave you some links :) Good luck!

Comment: If your clients trust you, it is possible that you keep the refresh token on server side (in a db etc, where you can auto-refresh the refresh token before invalidation), e.g. never disclose refresh token to the client, first login excluded since the first refresh token and access token comes from the client browser. Then you can let clients log in to your server / api and you query db using a hash of their password, and send the proper access token that is not equally sensitive. This is one approach, I have made many different approaches.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://github.com/neoighodaro-articles/csrf-attacks-laravel

Comment: Did someone ever solve this? Lot's of Laravel API + SPA seperated examples is only showing storing in localStorage..

Comment: Nope... Didn't get an answer that covers everything..

Comment: To me this kind of argument should be treated in the official doc... if passport aims to be a secure way to handle authentication this kind of scenario should be explained clearly. After days of research i see that almost nobody handle this the right way.

Answer (score 42):

I'll try to answer this in a generic way so that the answer is applicable across frameworks, implementations and languages because the answers to all the questions can be derived from the general protocol or algorithm specifications.

### Which OAuth 2.0 grant type should I use?

This is the first thing to be decided. When it comes to SPA, the two possible options are:

1. Authorization code grant (recommended, provided the client secret is stored on the server side)
2. Resource owner password credential grant

The reasons I don't mention Implicit grant type as an option are:

1. The client authentication step by providing client secret and authorization code is missing. So less security
2. The access token is sent back as a URL fragment (so that the token doesn't go to the server) which will continue to stay in browser history
3. If XSS attack occurs, the malicious script can very well send the token to a remote server in control of an attacker

(Client Credentials grant type is kept out of scope of this discussion as it is used when the client is not acting on behalf of a user. For e.g. a batch job)

In case of Authorization Code grant type, the authorization server is usually a different server from the resource server. It is better to keep the authorization server separate and use it as a common authorization server for all SPA within the organization. This is always the recommended solution.

Here (in the authorization code grant type) the flow looks like below:

1. the user clicks on the login button on the SPA landing page
2. the user is redirected to the authorization server login page. The client id is provided in the URL query parameter
3. The user enters his / her credentials and clicks on the login button. The username and password will be sent to the authorization server using HTTP POST. The credentials should be sent in the request body or header and NOT in the URL (as URLs are logged in browser history and application server). Also, the proper caching HTTP headers should be set, so that the credentials are not cached: `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`, `Pragma: no-cache`, `Expires: 0`
4. The authorization server authenticates the user against a user database (say, LDAP server) where the username and the hash of the user password (hashing algorithms like Argon2, PBKDF2, Bcrypt or Scrypt) is stored with a random salt
5. On successful authentication, the authorization server would retrieve from its database the redirect URL against the provided client id in the URL query parameter. The redirect URL is the resource server URL
6. The user will then be redirected to a resource server endpoint with a authorization code in the URL query parameter
7. The resource server will then do an HTTP POST request to the authorization server for access token. The authorization code, client id, client secret should go in the request body. (Appropriate caching headers as above should be used)
8. The authorization server would return the access token and the refresh token in response body or header (with the appropriate caching header as mentioned above)
9. The resource server will now redirect the user (HTTP response code 302) to the SPA URL by setting appropriate cookies (to be explained in detail below)

On the other hand, for resource owner password credential grant type, the authorization server and the resource server are same. It is easier to implement and can also be used if it suits the requirement and implementation timelines.

Also refer to my answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53988717/1235935) for further details on Resource Owner grant type.

It may be important to note here that in a SPA, all the protected routes should be enabled only after calling an appropriate service to ensure that valid tokens are present in the request. Similarly the protected APIs should also have appropriate filters to validate the access tokens.

### Why shouldn't I store the tokens in browser localstorage or sessionstorage?

Many SPAs do store access and / or refresh token in the browser localstorage or sessionstorage. The reason I think we shouldn't store the tokens in these browser storages are:

1. If XSS occurs, the malicious script can easily read the tokens from there and send them to a remote server. There on-wards the remote server or attacker would have no problem in impersonating the victim user.
2. localstorage and sessionstorage are not shared across sub-domains. So, if we have two SPA running on different sub-domains, we won't get the SSO functionality because the token stored by one app won't be available to the other app within the organization

If, however, the tokens are still stored in any of these browser storages, proper fingerprint must be included. Fingerprint is a cryptographically strong random string of bytes. The Base64 string of the raw string will then be stored in a `HttpOnly`, `Secure`, `SameSite` cookie with name prefix `__Secure-`. Proper values for `Domain` and `Path` attributes. A SHA256 hash of the string will also be passed in a claim of JWT. Thus Even if an XSS attack sends the JWT access token to an attacker controlled remote server, it cannot send the original string in cookie and as a result the server can reject the request based on the absence of the cookie. Also, XSS and script injection can be further mitigated by using an appropriate `content-security-policy` response header.

Note:

1. `SameSite=strict` ensures that the given cookie will not accompany the requests originated from a different site (AJAX or through following hyperlink). Simply put - any request originating from a site with the same "registrable domain" as the target site will be allowed. E.g. If "http://www.example.com" is the name of the site, the registrable domain is "example.com". For further details refer to Reference no. 3 in the last section below. Thus, it provides some protection against CSRF. However, this also means that if the URL is given is a forum, an authenticated user cannot follow the link. If that is a serious restriction for an application, `SameSite=lax` can be used which will allow cross-site requests as long as the HTTP methods are safe viz. GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE. Since CSRF is based on unsafe methods like POST, PUT, DELETE, `lax` still provides protection against CSRF
2. To allow a cookie to be passed in all requests to any sub-domain of "example.com", the domain attribute of the cookie should be set as "example.com"

### Why should I store access token and / or refresh token in cookies?

1. When storing the tokens in cookies, we can set the cookie as `secure` and `httpOnly`. Thus if XSS occurs, the malicious script cannot read and send them to remote server. XSS can still impersonate the user from the users' browser, but if the browser is closed, the script can't do further damage. `secure` flag ensures that the tokens cannot be sent over unsecured connections - SSL/TLS is mandatory
2. Setting the root domain in the cookie as `domain=example.com`, for example, ensures that the cookie is accessible across all sub-domains. Thus, different apps and servers within the organization can use the same tokens. Login is required only once

### How do I validate the token?

Tokens are usually JWT tokens. Usually the contents of the token are not secret. Hence they are usually not encrypted. If encryption is required (maybe because some sensitive information is also being passed within the token), there is a separate specification JWE. Even if encryption is not required, we need to ensure the integrity of the tokens. No one (user or the attacker) should be able to modify the tokens. If they do, the server should be able to detect that and deny all requests with the forged tokens. To ensure this integrity, the JWT tokens are digitally signed using an algorithm like HmacSHA256. In order to generate this signature, a secret key is required. The authorization server will own and protect the secret. Whenever the authorization server api is invoked to validate a token, the authorization server would recalculate the HMAC on the passed token. If it doesn't match with the input HMAC, it gives back a negative response. The JWT token are returned or stored in a Base64 encoded format.

However, for every API call on the resource server, the authorization server is not involved to validate the token. The resource server can cache the tokens issued by the authorization server. The resource server can use an in-memory data grid (viz. Redis) or, if everything cannot be stored in RAM, an LSM based DB (viz Riak with Level DB) to store the tokens.

For every API call, the resource server would check its cache.

1. If the access token is not present in the cache, APIs should return an appropriate response message and 401 response code such that the SPA can redirect the user to an appropriate page where the user would be requested to re-login
2. If the access token is valid but expired (Note, the JWT tokens usually contain the username and the expiry date among other things), APIs should return an appropriate response message and 401 response code such that the SPA can invoke an appropriate resource server API to renew the access token with the refresh token (with appropriate cache headers). The server would then invoke the authorization server with access token, refresh token and client secret and the authorization server can return the new access and refresh tokens which eventually flow down to the SPA (with appropriate cache headers). Then the client needs to retry the original request. All this will be handled by the system without user intervention. A separate cookie could be created for storing refresh token similar to access token but with appropriate value for `Path` attribute, so that the refresh token do not accompany every request, but available only in renewal requests
3. If the refresh token is invalid or expired, APIs should return an appropriate response message and 401 response code such that the SPA can redirect the user to an appropriate page where the user would be requested to re-login

### Why do we need two tokens - access token and refresh token?

1. Access token usually have a short validity period, say 30 minutes. Refresh token usually have a longer validity period, say 6 months. If the access token is somehow compromised, the attacker can impersonate the victim user only as long as the access token is valid. Since the attacker won't have the client secret, it cannot request the authorization server for a new access token. Attacker can however request the resource server for token renewal (as in the above setup, the renewal request is going through the resource server to avoid storing the client secret in browser), but given the other steps taken it is unlikely and moreover the server can take additional protection measures based on IP address.
2. If this short validity period of the access token helps the authorization server to revoke the issued tokens from the clients, if required. The authorization server can also maintain a cache of the issued tokens. The administrators of the system can then, if required, mark certain users' tokens as revoked. On access token expiry, when the resource server will go to the authorization server, the user will be forced to login again.

### What about CSRF?

1. In order to protect the user from CSRF, we can follow the approach followed in frameworks like Angular (as explained in the Angular HttpClient [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection) where the server has to send a non-HttpOnly cookie (in other words a readable cookie) containing a unique unpredictable value for that particular session. It should be a cryptographically strong random value. The client will then always read the cookie and send the value in a custom HTTP header (except GET & HEAD requests which are not supposed to have any state changing logic. Note CSRF cannot read anything from the target web app due to same origin policy) so that the server can verify the value from the header and the cookie. Since the cross domain forms cannot read the cookie or set a custom header, in case of CSRF requests, the custom header value will be missing and the server would be able to detect the attack
2. To protect the application from login CSRF, always check the `referer` header and accept requests only when `referer` is a trusted domain. If `referer` header is absent or a non-whitelisted domain, simply reject the request. When using SSL/TLS `referrer` is usually present. Landing pages (that is mostly informational and not containing login form or any secured content may be little relaxed ​and allow requests with missing `referer` header
3. `TRACE` HTTP method should be blocked in the server as this can be used to read the `httpOnly` cookie
4. Also, set the header
   `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=<expire-time>; includeSubDomains`​ to allow only secured connections to prevent any man-in-the-middle overwrite the CSRF cookies from a sub-domain
5. Additionally, the `SameSite` setting as mentioned above should be used
6. State Variable (Auth0 uses it) - The client will generate and pass with every request a cryptographically strong random nonce which the server will echo back along with its response allowing the client to validate the nonce. It's explained in [Auth0 doc](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state#csrf-attacks)

Finally, SSL/TLS is mandatory for all communications - as on today, TLS versions below 1.1 are not acceptable for PCI/DSS compliance. Proper cipher suites should be used to ensure forward secrecy and authenticated encryption. Also, the access and refresh tokens should be blacklisted as soon as the user explicitly clicks on "Logout" to prevent any possibility of token misuse.

### References

1. [RFC 6749 - OAuth2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
2. [OWASP JWT Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java.md)
3. [SameSite Cookie IETF Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07)
4. [Cookie Prefixes](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/cookie-prefixes/)
5. [RFC 6265 - Cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

Comment: Thank you for the generic overview, upvoted as it is good info. I am still looking for the Laravel 5.6 specific password grant implementation guide though. As none of the answers so far cover everything, just portions here and there, but not an implementable password grant httpOnly secure cookie implementation flow :/

Comment: @Saptarshi Basu "Since the attacker won't have the client secret, it cannot request the authorization server for a new access token." If possible can you elaborate that for me please. If attacker gets hand on refresh token can't they easily create access tokens?

Comment: @UjjwalJungThapa Usually, in all the implementations you need to provide a client secret along with the refresh token to get a new access token. Note that you always give away the refresh token to the browser or device connecting to your service. Anyone who has access to the device can get hold of the refresh token. Unless there is a secret, anyone can generate a new token.

Comment: @Saptarshi Basu can you please tell me what you mean by client secret since for jwt the secret key is stored only on server right? I thought client only sends refresh token.

Comment: @UjjwalJungThapa Refer to section 2.3.1 of RFC 6749 (link given in the reference section). All resource servers need to authenticate themselves with the authorization server using a client id and client secret (you can consider this as an username and password owned by the resource server)

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu How do you provide user detail to the SPA client after the user is authenticated by the server using auth code? Is it safe to expose another endpoint which provides details of the user in clear JSON response?

Comment: @RahulMisra if you mean the full name of the user, employee id etc., they are usually available in the JWT token claims. No API call is needed.

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu the cookie sent from the server to SPA is httponly and it cannot read it. No tokens are sent to the SPA as the sign-in is handled by a server side page which SPA redirects to. Server is the oauth client and sets a cookie on the SPA. All Authorised API calls succeed but the SPA wants to know these basic details as you mentioned.

Comment: @RahulMisra You're right. I have been using Okta for quite some time in my day-job and so missed that point in my last response. In your case I think a call to the resource server (which has access to the token) for user details should be okay. Once the API returns the user details (not the token), it can be cached

Answer (score 16):

Laravel Passport JWT

1. To use this feature you need to disable cookie serialization.
   Laravel 5.5 has an issue with serialization / unserialization of cookie values.
   You can read more about this here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade)
2. Make sure that

   - you have `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your blade template head
   - axios is set to use csrf_token on each request.

You should have something like this in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

3. Setup auth routes explained here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)
4. Setup passport explained here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport).

Important parts are:

- add the `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` trait to your `User` model
- set the `driver` option of the `api` authentication guard to `passport` in your `config/auth.php`
- add the `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,` middleware to your `web` middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Note you probably can skip migrations and creating clients.

5. Make a POST request to `/login` passing your credentials. You can make an AJAX request or normal form submit.

If the login request is AJAX (using axios) the response data will be the HTML but what are you interested at is the status code.

```
axios.get(
  '/login, 
  {
    email: 'user@email.com',
    password: 'secret',
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json', // set this header to get json validation errors.
    },
  },
).then(response => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
      // the cookie was set in browser
      // the response.data will be HTML string but I don't think you are interested in that
    }
    // do something in this case
}).catch(error => {
  if (error.response.status === 422) {
    // error.response.data is an object containing validation errors
  }
  // do something in this case
});
```

On login, the server finds the user by credentials provided, generates a token based on user info (id, email ...) (this token is not saved anywhere)
then the server returns a response with an encrypted cookie that contains the generated token.

6. Make an API call to a protected route.

Assuming that you have a protected route

`Route::get('protected', 'SomeController@protected')->middleware('auth:api');`

You can make an ajax call using axios as normal. The cookies are automatically set.

```
axios.get('/api/protected')
  .then(response => {
    // do something with the response
  }).catch(error => {
    // do something with this case of error
  });
```

When the server receives the call decrypts the request `laravel_cookie` and get user information (ex: id, email ...)
Then with that user info does a database lookup to check if the user exists.
If the user is found then the user is authorized to access the requested resource.
Else a 401 is returned.

Invalidating the JWT token. As you mention the comment there's no need to worry about this since this token is not saved anywhere on the server.

### Update

Regarding point 3 Laravel 5.6 Auth has a new method `logoutOtherDevices`. You can learn more from here (https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-6/episodes/7)
since the documentation is very light.

If you can't update your Laravel version you can check it out how is done in 5.6 and build your own implementation for 5.5

Point 4 from your question. Take a look at controllers found in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`.

Regarding access_tokens and refresh_tokens this is a totally different and more complex approach. 
You can find lots of tutorials online explaining how to do it.

I hope it helps.

PS. Have a Happy New Year!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response; it's very important to have points 3 and 4 in my question addressed as well. If a device is lost or stolen, we need to be able to revoke access, for example, via Change Password, that would then revoke all tokens linked to the user's device(s). The issue with the `CreateFreshApiToken` is that we are not able to revoke that user's token(s), so a lost/stolen device will always be active with no way to revoke. If you also think of "log out from all devices" same sort of functionality is needed, where active token(s) will be revoked for the given user. How do we do that?

Comment: Thank you for the update, I am aiming for the best security possible with Passport Authentication. It seems that the password grant with an `access_token` and `refresh_token` combo is the recommended way to go. That way even the app admin can revoke user tokens, to instantly render their next request token useless and prompt a logout from the app. The worry with your approach is if someone grabs hold of another user's `CreateFreshApiToken` token, now they can be them forever, right? Admin can't revoke that token so they can have infinite access I think. Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Happy New Year :) Any idea about my last comment?

Comment: Hey @Wonka! Sorry for my slow reply. I'm not sure I understand your requirements. You want a flow that uses some oauth grant (like password grant) instead of JWT? In this case how will you store client id and client secret on the browser if you have more clients?

Comment: Let's say that you authenticate a user and the server will set the `refresh_token` in a httpOnly cookie. How do you access that to get a new `access_token`? httpOnly cookies cannot be read with JS.

Comment: That's basically one of the main issues, but I think when the server after login sends the httpOnly cookie with the access token as a response header, it will be passed back to the sever with each api request as a request header. The server needs to somehow check the token, and if token expires/d, should somehow issue/reissue a refresh token in the response header without login again. Maybe via middleware, not sure. But the app server must be able to revoke tokens too, say for a hijacked account access/refresh token to kick user off so they'll have to login via username/password again.

Comment: Let's say that you achieve your flow. JS make a post request to some login endpoint and the server sets an access_token into cookie. your client will use that for each request. When the access_token expires server will refresh automatically that token. My question is how is this secure? If I get your cookie then I can use that token always because the server will automatically renew it. See my point? And where I'm confused about your flow?

Comment: I'm def not a security expert, but I think if the `access_token` and `refresh_token` have a short validity period, ~10 minutes, maybe it will render the "stolen" cookie useless? That's my guess.. I was hoping someone with more experience who implemented this would provide a solution touching on this point and others. Your approach is the easiest to implement, and I tried it before, but not being able to revoke a user token(s) makes it impossible for the app server to revoke access to a bad user. I've been stuck for 3 weeks+ on this and it's truly hard to find a solution that covers everything.

Comment: @Wonka I'm not sure how to help you because I don't know a lot of things about your app but maybe this article https://medium.com/lightrail/getting-token-authentication-right-in-a-stateless-single-page-application-57d0c6474e3 will give you some hints.

Comment: Sorry about the back and forth on your solution, but here is the scenario I am really trying to solve, and if it works with your solution, then indeed it is the correct answer. User logs in from phone, thief steals the phone, so user logs in from computer and changes password to prevent thief from accessing their phone logged in account. Will the thief be logged out from phone with this flow? I just want to make sure that once the user changes their password, it will disable the thief from any further access on the stolen device.

Answer (score 8):

- Laravel Passport is an implementation of The PHP League's OAuth Server
- The password grant type can be used for username + password authentication
- Remember to hide your client credentials by making the auth request in a proxy
- Save the refresh token in a HttpOnly cookie to minimize the risk of XSS attacks

More information you can see here

http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I came across this tutorial already. The issue I have with it is it says "6. The client saves the access token in storage, for instance a browser app saves it in localStorage" and I am just trying to have the cookie be automatically sent back, kind of like the laravel_token works, but laravel_token doesn't enable us to destroy the jwt in it. So just trying to have it work with http cookies only, otherwise if someone can access your local storage, they can grab your access token, making the cookie useless. Also the article doesn't touch on CSRF integration.

Comment: Yes I get you that you need something just like this it is without Laravel Passport but you can see example how to prevent cyber attacks

Comment: I hope there is a simpler way to do the 5 points in my original question using Laravel 5.5, with Passport, without local storage for api calls, just the cookie + CSRF integration. I think there should be a better/simpler way to achieve those 5 points with Passport and Laravel 5.5. I'll keep the question open, hopefully we get an answer addressing all the above points. I know many people are looking for the same thing, but everything seems outdated or not complete 100%, and there is no one source/guide/laracast/SO question showing how to do this correctly/completely 100% with L5.5/Passport.

Comment: I think so it is a good idea and you are right if you would like and other get full information that need. I will gladly to help you with this. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have also implemented Laravel passport in my project and I think I have covered most of the points which you have mentioned in your question.

1. I have used the password grant for generating an access token and refresh token. You can follow [these](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client) steps to set up the passport and implement the passport grant. 
   In your login method, you have to validate the user credentials and generate the tokens and attach the cookie([Attaching cookie to the response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)) to the response.  If you need I can get you some examples.
2. I have added two middleware for CORS(Handling the incoming request headers) and to check if the incoming access token is valid or not if not valid generate the access token from stored refresh token ([Refreshing token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#refreshing-tokens)). I can show you the example.
3. After login, all the request from the client side should contain the Authorization header(`Authorization: Bearer <token>`).

Let me know if you are clear with the above points.

Comment: I added an update, the 2nd point in the update I believe is supposed to send/receive  the secure httpOnly cookie with the request/response header, as opposed to the `Authorization: Bearer <token>`. I am also looking for a solution which covers all the above points and works well and coherently together.

Comment: In your case, you have added CreateFreshApiToken which works with the personal access token. You can't refresh or revoke the personal access token they are a long-lived token but you can adjust its expiration.

Comment: In my 3rd point use case (stolen device), log user account out from other signed in devices where they are/were active, change password, etc... These are all instances where the application server should be able to immediately revoke access to the currently logged in user, and render their tokens useless. This question and mapping out the solution with this scenario is very confusing to me.

Comment: If the user is logged out or changed his password so you have the option to delete the stored token or set the revoked flag as true. If you want full control over your tokens I would suggest you go with the password grant method.

Comment: Yup I agree that the password grant method should be the way to go, but I'm looking for an answer which implements it while addressing the original question's 5 points usage/implementation to paint a complete usable guide how the entire system will work from server to client back to server.

Comment: Can you share some code on your above points? Are you able to integrate an httpOnly secure cookie for access/refresh token and csrf? We're trying to avoid `Authorization: Bearer <token>` with local storage and instead for the request/response use the secure httpOnly cookie with the revokable token/csrf.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses refer this link

Comment: Thank you for getting back, but I have already read the docs many times. I still don't get how to implement all the pieces in order to make everything work together, that's why I asked this question :) I and many others are looking for an implementable solution, but I have yet to find one covering all aspects and ready to implement like a guide.

Comment: can you mention your Laravel version and which database you are using

Comment: Laravel 5.6/MySQL