# Is there any benefit for storing JWT in both a cookie and local storage?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, xss, csrf

I'm attempting write an authentication system for a node.js api using express. I've noticed that if I am going to use a JWT for authentication tokens, I have two options...

1.) Store the token in a cookie, and add CSRF protection. 
2.) Have the client send the token in the Auth Header and add XSS protection.

My question is, is there any benefit to storing the auth token in a cookie, and having the client send it in the Auth Header for authentication? This way if for some reason the CSRF protection fell through, the request would fail if there was no authentication token in the header. Also, if XSS protection fell through, the request would still require the auth token in a cookie. I guess my thought is that this would provide more protection, and the only way it could fail is through a successful XSS attack followed by a successful CSRF attack.

Follow up question: Are CSRF tokens a full proof protection technique against CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I recommend that you go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011649/1235935) answer first. I hope I've bern able to address your queries about CSRF and XSS here and why and how we should use cookie.

Secondly, your approach of using localstorage along with cookie is good. The only problem I see is localstorage cannot be used across sub domains. If you use cookie and set the cookie domain as `example.com` (replace example with your organization domain), it will be valid across all sub domains. Thus a user authenticated by your authorization server can seamlessly login to app1.example.com and app2.example.com. You won't be able to do this with localstorage.

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you! I didn't think of the localstorage issue between subdomains.