# Handling the oauth token in a website/service

Tags: web-services, security, encryption, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have created a website which allows the user to authenticate against oauth2 (from another provider), the basic flow is (assuming a new user):

1. The user loads my webpage
2. An OAuth request token key and secret is provided by the OAuth endpoint
3. I store the request token into the user's cookies
4. The user is redirected to the OAuth authentication page from an external provider
5. The user accepts and is redirected by to my webpage with URL parameters which specify the OAuth verifier and OAuth token
6. Using the request token (retrieved from cookies) and OAuth verifier (passed via URL parameters), I am able to get an access token key and secret from the OAuth endpoint.
7. I am now able to authenticate with the providers API and use that to get the logged in user ID.
8. I then store into a MySQL database, the user ID, a token which I generate as a random unsigned integer, OAuth token and OAuth secret. In cases of the token I generate already being in the database, I just continue in a loop until a unique token is generated. The MySQL database has a strong name, username and password. The database user can only access the table in question and only has privileges to add an entry, delete an entry and make a query.
9. I clear the request token from the user's cookies and instead store the user ID and my generated token.

When a user comes back to my website, I check if they have the user ID and token stored in their cookies, if so I attempt to look up the OAuth token and secret from MySQL. If they are found, I test they are still valid (does the API endpoint accept them) and if so, the user remains 'logged in' to my website. In cases where the user ID or token isn't found in MySQL or cases where it **is** found, but is **not** accepted by the endpoint (expired?), I just go back through the flow above.

The above all works correctly, new users can successfully authenticate, returning users find the website remembers them. I do not expose the OAuth token key or secret to the user and instead, give the user this token ID which I generate.

Are there any problems with what I am doing?

- Should I be encrypting the OAuth token key and secret in my database?
- Is there a problem with the fact if someone was to gain access to the token I generate, along with the user ID, they would be able to call my scripts. Is this a problem?
- Should I be encrypting the user ID and token I generate before storing it in the user's cookies? Taking into account, ultimately whatever is stored in the user's cookies will get passed to my script, so if I were to encrypt, store to cookies, then next time read from cookies and decrypt, the user would still be able to access my endpoints by simply passing the encrypted version (assuming the server decrypts, if the client decrypts then the decryption key would be accessible via the users browser anyway), which doesn't immediately appear to offer any further security.

My goal is to tighten up the steps above so it is deemed robust and secure. The actual use case for my web site means it'll only have a tiny number of users (if any) using it. It was more of a learning process for me, combined with implementing something I actually need. But for the learning aspect alone, I would like to make everything sensible and secure. I am not trying to be overly pedantic and implement steps no other similar websites would implement, basically I would like my site to be secure enough that if there ever was a problem, no one could point a finger at me and say I didn't implement an adequate security system.

Comment: I think you'd find answers to all the queries in this answer link. If not, let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011649/1235935

Comment: You seems to over-complicate the things, indeed read the linked resource  by Saptarshi and then try to rework your flow. You may as well follow the [simplyfied](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) blog. Most probably you are looging for the *code grant* OAuth flow.

Comment: At the moment I have 9 steps if you can provide a shorter/less complicated set of steps I can evaluate.