# How to implement JWT with angular5

Tags: php, authentication, jwt, angular5

I have a little problem.
Our application is made with Angular5 and PHP in WebApi.

But as it's new for me, I never did authentication or routing permission.
But I want to use the JWT (JSON Web Tokens) to make sessions and permissions.

Does someone have any tips or good explains on how work JWT / how it could be implemented..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011649/1235935