# Oauth2: Authenticate single page app without client secret when secret is required by service

Tags: vue.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, quire-api

I would like to create an integration with [quire.io](https://quire.io/dev), which currently only supports the Oauth2 authorization_code flow ***with*** `client_secret`. 
This causes me a problem because my application will need a dashboard so users can configure it.

So far I have been trying to get a token on a backend server (which has the secret) and then send the token to the client in a cookie as a JWT.
Is there a way I can securely access the quire api from my frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [authorization_code flow **without** client secret](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/8) hasn't been implemented yet (different priorities).
For now you'll need the extra server to keep the `client_secret` in a secure place.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any suggestions on how I can use that server? As I wrote in my question, I have been trying to get a token on a backend server, then return the token to the client, is this what you mean?

Comment: yes that's what I meant:
the scenario is described here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/security-considerations/ however they leave it vaguely open how the communication between the SPA and the "companion server" should continue after the the access token was received by the "companion server", i wonder if that's described elsewhere in more detail.

Comment: after reading this lengthy answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678019/laravel-5-6-passport-jwt-httponly-cookie-spa-authentication-for-self-consuming/54011649#54011649 things get quite complicated ... storing the access_token in the browser seems to be discouraged ... not 100% sure what this implies